# Matplotlib basemap: zoom into orthographic projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot an area in orthographic projection in order to layer it together with an image from satellite like this one 
[image: satellite image]

So I've tried to zoom into an orthographic projection like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748226/orthographic-projection-python)

Using this code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

map = Basemap(projection = 'ortho', lon_0 = 15, lat_0 = 68,\
               resolution = 'c')

lllon = 7
urlon = 21
lllat = 67
urlat = 70

xmin, ymin = map(lllon, lllat)
xmax, ymax = map(urlon, urlat)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = .1)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,1), linewidth = .01)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-80,80,.25), linewidth = .01)
```

and some more to plot lines, but that results in an image that is correct in center and proportion but not cropped to the area specified, like this:

[image: map]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: The axis limits need to be set *after* drawing on the map.

Comment: Even if I set the axis limits at the end of the script I still get the complete disc view. So this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've added the code that works to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from the question produces a full orthographic projection as seen in [the example](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/ortho.html).

> The orthographic projection displays the earth as a satellite (in an orbit infinitely high above the earth) would see it.

In order to show only part of it, you can supply the edges of the map to the `Basemap` call.

Unfortunately, [you cannot use the lat/lon values for this](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/164), but instead need to use the `x,y` values.

The following would hence work:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

m = Basemap(projection = 'ortho', lon_0 = 0, lat_0 = 10,
            llcrnrx=-3000000, llcrnry=1000000, urcrnrx=3000000, urcrnry=6000000, 
            resolution = 'c')

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 1)
m.drawcountries()

plt.show()
```

[image]

A different option is shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748226/orthographic-projection-python) which is to set axes limits after the map is drawn.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

map = Basemap(projection = 'ortho', lon_0 = 15, lat_0 = 68,\
               resolution = 'l')

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 1)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,1), linewidth = 1)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-80,80,.25), linewidth = 1)

lllon = 7
urlon = 21
lllat = 67
urlat = 70

xmin, ymin = map(lllon, lllat)
xmax, ymax = map(urlon, urlat)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748226/orthographic-projection-python) example does no longer work? Is there a way to find out which llcrnrx correspond to which longitude? And same for latitude?

Comment: Thanks again! Works now. It did not work in the beginning, because I had set the bounding box to 'tight', when saving the figure `fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.savefig('/home/map.png', dpi = 600, bbox_inches = 'tight')`and that way it saved the whole disc.