# Python: Adding a zoom variable for matplotlib map

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to add a zoom variable to the following code to increase / decrease the zoom (scale) of the map this code produces:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
latitudes = [24.49522]
longitudes = [46.5057713]

# Create a new Basemap instance with the desired map projection
m = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0=0, lon_0=0, resolution='h',
            area_thresh=1000.0, llcrnrlon=min(longitudes)-1, llcrnrlat=min(latitudes)-1,
            urcrnrlon=max(longitudes)+1, urcrnrlat=max(latitudes)+1, epsg=4326)

# Set the map type to satellite view
m.arcgisimage(epsg=4326, xpixels=1000, verbose=False)

# Plot the coordinates on the map
x, y = m(longitudes, latitudes)
m.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=20)

# Add a custom scale bar to the map
#plt.text(0.5, -0.05, 'Scale: 10 km', ha='center', va='bottom', transform=plt.gca().transAxes)

# Set the title of the map
#plt.title('Map of One Coordinate')

# Save the map as a JPEG file
plt.savefig('map.jpg', dpi=300
```

I've tried adding this:

```
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (x, y)
```

But it seems to just increase the size of the image rather than the scale / level of zoom

Comment: Use map extents (specified by llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat) to get different zoom/scsle_level of image. Figsize does nothing about zoom level of map data.

Comment: Cand find what you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271039/matplotlib-basemap-zoom-into-orthographic-projection